# Use of embryo stem cells: Is Islam against it?

Tags: practical-islam, life

Assalamualaikum, I'm involved in a personal work in which I have to do a presentation on tissue regeneration using embryo cells. In the presentation there are a part of biology and a second part of bioethics and philosophy.It is obvious that it is a very delicate argument and I have to be really careful on what I'm going to say. In the presentation ,mainly, I will talk about the position taken by the catholic religion because my audience will be composed by catholics but my problem is that I really don't know what is the position taken by the main religions (including mine, Islam) in this type of argument. My question is: **Do Islam agrees or disagrees with the use of embryo stem cells? And why?** Sorry for my english and thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is that you're not explaining exactly your confusion, why would we consider stem cells as a person??

Comment: I committed a mistake, sorry. Considering embryo as a person is a question that I will have to deal with in my presentation. My doubt is if Islam agrees (or disagrees) in using embryo stem cells in certain case as the regeneration of dead tissues

Comment: *[Can “doubt” sometimes mean “question”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Soul

In Islam the **soul** is the main object of judgment and evaluation, a soul matured and healthy enough to decide rationally and with considerations of his decision's consequences.

Therefore, tissues and body organs are not considered **A** person, and many operations like transplantation or using embryo cells to regenerate a part of body are not considered a Haraam act, BUT

## [Human cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_cloning#Uses.2C_actual_and_potential)

There is this problem that using embryo cells we could actually regenerate a whole complete new person and actually give birth to a new person, which has been done on plants and animals but banned to be tested on humans in several countries (although suspected to be tested by some secret labs), As you probably know this Phenomenon is more than just regenerating a tissue it aims at killing a person and use of its organs who could **later be born**, this is obvious to be against any moral values.

**Summarizing:** any interference in stopping the process of a human birth is not accepted, So you need to judge any of such kind operations by giving details about if it is about stopping the process of birth or whether it could never end up in a birth.